# Ag-grid angular: How to get access to the status of the vertical scroll bar (ScrollVisibleService)

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm trying to get the value (true/false) which tells if the vertical scroll bar is visible.

I saw that there is a service, [**ScrollVisibleService**](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/9565c219b6210aa85fa833c929d0728f9d163a91/community-modules/core/src/ts/gridPanel/scrollVisibleService.ts), which can provide that. It's just that I could not manage to get the service providing any value. It looks like the service has to be instantiated somehow, injection does not work.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use public method **isVerticalScrollShowing()** from scrollVisibleService